# Disable bold character under cursor

Tags: gvim, colorscheme, cursor

This might be a newbie question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

I've created a custom colorscheme, but I don't know how to stop the character behind the cursor from becoming bold.

This is the `Cursor` line from my theme file.

[image: Vim theme]

It might be hard to see on the image but the `g` after the cursor is bold, or just darker.

Usually `gui=NONE` removes any effects from other elements. But this doesn't seem to work with the cursor.

Comment: This must be something related to gui vim only. Might even be a bug. Or just a feature to make sure the character behind the cursor is not hard to see. So, basically, if you're concerned about your colorscheme, you've nothing else to do. Maybe you could check if it also happens with other colorschemes. Most probably it does. But if it doesn't, you can then easily backtrack and pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what machine your using, but on my iMac I had the exact same issue and I've finally fixed it. The solution was to go to preferences and uncheck "Use Core Text renderer".

I no longer have the issue and as far as I can tell, there hasn't been any adverse affects from doing this.